# Specify ABSPATH in jQuery url

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm building a custom jQuery form and I need to specify the siteurl in the url that loads /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

I place this code in the template that has the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#newFeedbackForm').submit(ajaxSubmit); 
function ajaxSubmit(){
    var newFeedbackForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: <?php get_bloginfo('siteurl'); ?> . "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: newFeedbackForm,
        success:function(data){
            jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

When I submit the form I get a **404 error** with all the form inputs in the URL. I'm thinking ajax isn't being called right to handle the form and apply the function of the hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="addComment"/>
```

Working backwards, here is the addComment function:

```
function addComment(){
global $wpdb;

$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$no_results_comment = $_POST['no_results_comment'];

// EXTRA
$date = time(); // UNIX TIMESTAMP

if($wpdb->insert('wp_no_results_feedback',array(
    'topic' => $topic,                                                      
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'no_results_comment' => $no_results_comment,
    'date' => $date
    ))===FALSE){
        echo "Error";           
    }else{
        echo "Thanks for your feedback. We will get back to you shortly.";
    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_addComment','addComment');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addComment','addComment');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JavaScript is running in the admin, you don't need to set an explicit path to admin-ajax.php. It's always available as a JS variable called "ajaxurl". You can see [an example of this in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side), under the heading "AJAX on the Administration Side"

Ajaxurl is, unfortunately, not available on the frontend by default. But you can use a trcik with wp_localize_script() to declare it in a custom namespace, and use it in your frontend scripts. This is a really handy trick. More in [this blog post](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#admin-ajax) (also linked from that Codex article).

Answer (score 2):

Following @MathSmath 's answer, you can make `ajaxurl` available in the front end using this snippet:

```
add_action('wp_head','pluginname_ajaxurl');
function pluginname_ajaxurl() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

And you need to pass the action name to the `jQuery.ajax` function as follows:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    action: 'addComment'
    type:"POST",
    data: newFeedbackForm,
    success:function(data){
        jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @MathSmath's answer

> If your JavaScript is running in the admin, you don't need to set an
>   explicit path to admin-ajax.php. It's always available as a JS
>   variable called "ajaxurl". You can see an example of this in the
>   Codex, under the heading "AJAX on the Administration Side"
>
> Ajaxurl is, unfortunately, not available on the frontend by default.
>   But you can use a trcik with wp_localize_script() to declare it in a
>   custom namespace, and use it in your frontend scripts. This is a
>   really handy trick. More in this blog post (also linked from that
>   Codex article).

you should make the AJAX url global available via `wp_localize_script`.

Furthermore I'd recommend the separation of your HTML and JS Code.

You can achieve this like this:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_localize_script('jquery', 'myAjax', array(
        'url'        => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax', get_template_directory_uri().'/path/to/my_ajax.js', array('jquery') );
}

add_action('enqueue_scripts','my_enqueue_scripts');
```

your JS file e.g. `my_ajax.js`

```
jQuery('#newFeedbackForm').submit(ajaxSubmit); 
function ajaxSubmit(){
    var newFeedbackForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: myAjax.url,
        data: newFeedbackForm,
        success:function(data){
            jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```